# Twitter api not working in terminal

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

Am using the twitter gem to connect to the twitter streaming api.

When i run the code in the console in sublime text 2, everything works as it should and am getting the results from the api. However when i try to run the script from the terminal i get this error:

```
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.15.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:16:in `initialize': Can't assign requested address - connect(2) for "199.16.156.217" port  (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

Am only using the example code from the github page of the twitter gem.
https://github.com/sferik/twitter

```
client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
client.sample do |object|
  puts object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
end
```

Do anyone know why i get this error, and how i can fix this?

Comment: have you added your developer tokens/keys? :) I just copied and paste (of course with my own token, secret, etc.) your code to my ruby shell, and it worked ok.

Comment: yes, i have, i dont believe it is anything wrong with the code since it is working in the sublime text 2 console.

Comment: it will not fit here good, so, i'll add my code to the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue with the twitter gem, using an updated version from GitHub solved the problem.
https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/709

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'twitter'
while true
config = {
            :consumer_key => CONSUMER_KEY,
            :consumer_secret => COMSUMER_SECRET,
            :access_token => ACCESS_TOKEN,
            :access_token_secret => ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        }

    sClient = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new(config)
    topics = ['edelweiss', 'rose']
    sClient.filter(:track => topics.join(',')) do |tweet|
        if tweet.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
          puts "#{tweet.user.screen_name}: #{tweet.text}"
        end
    end
end
```

running code

```
$ ruby lasswi.rb 
Suphatra_Rfc: RT @GGiftfyy: Rose Gold ในมือนั้นอิจเเรงงงง  เครื่องเก่าโยนมาทางนี้ก็ได้นะเพ่~ น้องพร้อมเสมอ #งานซูมต้องมา #อยากได้อ่ะอยากได้  http://t.…
CBullsfans: Jimmy Butler Reportedly Doesn't Respect Derrick Rose's Work Ethic http://t.co/3Ikjvvjuth #Bulls #NBA
sobinasalvez: RT @iPhoneTeam: Rose gold everything http://t.co/1DLhXokknu
magicearth_: RT @magazine_wmw: Rose-ringed parakeets in flight on their way to roost in an urban cemetery in London, England.
Photograph: Sam Hobson htt…
demoo2012: Rose, use this pic 

@Razana96 http://t.co/uAwS9JdHyl
EndearingImages: New artwork for sale! - "Grace" - http://t.co/ugpIaxABqg @fineartamerica http://t.co/jg0e3eDNll
LoveKnitting: Great rose workshop with @NickyKnits at #TheKnittingandStitchingShow such a lovely lady! @twistedthread http://t.co/rV0Bsjg63t
camarillonican4: Brand New Sealed - Apple iPhone 6S Plus - 64GB - Rose Gold - UNLOCKED http://t.co/ygFPoN7pLO http://t.co/mqXKJmmrNz
Dekho00: RT @PAPIGFUNK: Giveaway ENDING on Sunday! Enter Now- iPhone 6S Plus - Rose Gold - Unboxing + Giveaway! https://t.co/02ONZ6D8IS #iPhone6SPlu…
souravmishra1: RT @RHIndia: "Only in art will the lion lie down with the lamb, and the rose grow without thorn." - Martin Amis​ #RandomAmis http://t.co/MT…
exol_lzw0112: RT @DOThFanclub: [Preview] 151009 ONE K Concert (cr.Like a star, Lovely Rose, Chibimori)
อันนยอง~~ http://t.co/w8vvE40dEK
BruhninhaD: Livro: Hugo &amp; Rose da Editora Agir
Será o correto deixar a realidade para viver um sonho?http://t.co/OfxkKrzBog #books #book #livros #blog
```